# API Result string to JSON

Tags: c#, json

I chained an API and got this result.

```
 string result = "YM,BAN,AME,txtBAN,txtNAME,DESCRIPTION,txtRANGE
    2015-01,11111111,test1,11111111,test1,(15-1062TPX) 2.0mm JO-M1937 test 380g 54",5
    2015-01,22222222,test2,22222222,test2,bl 2.0mm JO-M1937 test 380g 54",5
    2015-01,33333333,test3,33333333,test3,(15-1062TPX) 2.0mm JO-M1937 test 380g 54",5
    2015-01,44444444,test4,44444444,test4,bl 2.0mm JO-M1937 test 380g 54",5"
```

I want to change to this
Program is C#
I'm thinking about it now except
Spilt is there a better way?
Because I want to bring the value into the MODEL and write it to the database.

```
[
   {
      "YM":"2015-01",
      "BAN":"11111111",
      "AME":"test1",
      "txtBAN":"11111111",
      "DESCRIPTION":"(15-1062TPX) 2.0mm JO-M1937 test 380g 54",
      "txtRANGE":5
   },
   {
      "YM":"2015-01",
      "BAN":"11111111",
      "AME":"test1",
      "txtBAN":"11111111",
      "DESCRIPTION":"(15-1062TPX) 2.0mm JO-M1937 test 380g 54",
      "txtRANGE":5
   }
]
```

Comment: It appears to be the contents of a CSV file, so I'd say you want a CSV parsing library. Using a library such as CsvHelper, you could directly load the records into C# class instances, and then immediately serialize them.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar What I got is indeed the content of a CSV file, but because it is encrypted, it is finally changed to a string to pick up his result.

Comment: OK, you gave me direction, I'll try again,
thanks